# bi-directional operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

### Code

Vector.h

```
friend Vector& operator* (const double &factor, const Vector &v);
friend Vector& operator* (const Vector &v,const double &factor);
```

Vector.cpp

```
Vector& operator *(const double &factor, Vector &v){
    v.x=v.x*factor;
    v.y=v.y*factor;
    return v;
}
Vector& operator* (const Vector &v,const double &factor){
    return factor * v;
}
```

And for some readon i get the error at my Vector.cpp file, 
`Vector& operator* (const Vector &v,const double &factor)` -function

> undefined reference to `operator*(double const&, Vector const&)'

What am i doing wrong... ?

Comment: Your declaration and definition function signatures differ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, the error occurs, because your function declaration and definition signatures differ.

Anyway with a free standing operator function one would expect to get a new `Vector` instance, instead of getting a reference to the one passed.

Declare / define your operator functions as follows:

```
friend Vector operator* (const Vector &v,double factor);
friend Vector operator* (double factor, const Vector &v);

Vector operator *(double factor, const Vector &v) {
    Vector result = v;
    result.x=result.x*factor;
    result.y=result.y*factor;
    return result;
}

Vector operator* (const Vector &v,double factor) {
    return factor * v;
}
```